# Copying files in java (whole file not getting copied)

Tags: object, file-handling, object-oriented-analysis

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            File in = new File("in.txt");
            //File out = new File("out.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream("o.txt");
            //PrintWriter fw= new PrintWriter(out);

            if(!in.exists())
            {
                in.createNewFile();
                //System.out.println("Hey");
            }

            FileReader is = new FileReader(in);
            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(is);


            while(true)
            {
                if(in.canRead())
                {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(br.readLine());
                        fos.write((br.readLine()).getBytes());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                        fos.close();
                        br.close();

                        System.out.println("Im breaking");                      
                        break;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    fos.close();                    
                    System.out.println("closed");
                    break;
                )   

            }
    }
}
//end of file
```

- I am trying to copy text from one file to another file in Java.I know we can copy byte by byte but i want to do it using  strings! What's wrong?

Actual file : [image: Actual file]

Output file : [image: Output file (no formatting and the whole document is not getting copied)]

Comment: `fos.write(br.readLine() + "\n");` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you working with Java7 you can use `Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());` so you do not have to read the file. Or use `FileUtils.copyFile(source, dest);` from apache commons io.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    System.out.println(br.readLine());
                    fos.write((br.readLine()).getBytes());
```

You

1. Read one line, print it to stdout
2. Read another line, write it to `fos`

Thus some lines may be missing from output file. Also, `readLine()` drops the line-termination characters. You need to add them back by yourself.